# Looking for brief explanation of algo to find smallest containing interval in an interval tree

Tags: c#, algorithm, roslyn

I came across the following algo whilst browsing the Roslyn source. The file is ContextIntervalTree.cs in the Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Formatting namespace https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/src/Workspaces/Core/Portable/Formatting/ContextIntervalTree.cs. I want to understand it better as I have applications for similar algos in my own work. The tree that this algo runs on is a balanced binary tree ordered by the start endpoint of the interval which is stored in each node. In this function the parameter predicate tests whether the query interval is contained either exclusive or inclusive of endpoints. There are few things which are throwing me off.

1. Whilst descending the tree there is a test for `end < MaxEndValue(right)`. Given that we could be looking intervals inclusively shouldn't this be a `<=` test as is the case for descending the left side?
2. In the test checking for a better answer why is it necessary to have `Introspector.GetStart(result) <= Introspector.GetStart(currentNode.Value)`, I would though that just testing for a smaller length would be enough.
3. In other algos I have seen (e.g. http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/interval-tree/) if the left can hold the answer it is searched first and the right is only searched if we know the answer is not it the left subtree. So only one side or the other is searched, not both.
4. Whilst ascending the tree, if the inner loop is broken out of, control will return to the top of the out loop which could start to descend the tree again. Whats to stop the algo from alternating between ascending and descending?

I have a feeling this algo would be be more intuitive if it could be written recursively, but I am not sure how to go about doing that.

```
private T GetSmallestContainingIntervalWorker(int start, int length, Func<T, int, int, bool> predicate)
{
    var result = default(T);
    if (root == null || MaxEndValue(root) < start)
    {
        return result;
    }

    int end = start + length;

    // * our interval tree is a binary tree that is ordered by a start position.
    //
    // this method works by
    // 1. find a sub tree that has biggest "start" position that is smaller than given "start" by going down right side of a tree
    // 2. once it encounters a right sub tree that it can't go down anymore, move down to left sub tree once and try #1 again
    // 3. once it gets to the position where it can't find any smaller span (both left and
    //    right sub tree doesn't contain given span) start to check whether current node
    //    contains the given "span"
    // 4. move up the spin until it finds one that contains the "span" which should be smallest span that contains the given "span"
    // 5. if it is going up from right side, it make sure to check left side of tree first.
    using (var pooledObject = SharedPools.Default<Stack<Node>>().GetPooledObject())
    {
        var spineNodes = pooledObject.Object;

        spineNodes.Push(root);
        while (spineNodes.Count > 0)
        {
            var currentNode = spineNodes.Peek();

            // only goes to right if right tree contains given span
            if (Introspector.GetStart(currentNode.Value) <= start)
            {
                var right = currentNode.Right;
                if (right != null && end < MaxEndValue(right))
                {
                    spineNodes.Push(right);
                    continue;
                }
            }

            // right side, sub tree doesn't contain the given span, put current node on
            // stack, and move down to left sub tree
            var left = currentNode.Left;
            if (left != null && end <= MaxEndValue(left))
            {
                spineNodes.Push(left);
                continue;
            }

            // we reached the point, where we can't go down anymore.
            // now, go back up to find best answer
            while (spineNodes.Count > 0)
            {
                currentNode = spineNodes.Pop();

                // check whether current node meets condition
                if (predicate(currentNode.Value, start, length))
                {
                    // hold onto best answer
                    if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(result, default) ||
                        (Introspector.GetStart(result) <= Introspector.GetStart(currentNode.Value) &&
                            Introspector.GetLength(currentNode.Value) < Introspector.GetLength(result)))
                    {
                        result = currentNode.Value;
                    }
                }

                // there is no parent, result we currently have is the best answer
                if (spineNodes.Count == 0)
                {
                    return result;
                }

                var parentNode = spineNodes.Peek();

                // if we are under left side of parent node
                if (parentNode.Left == currentNode)
                {
                    // go one level up again
                    continue;
                }

                // okay, we are under right side of parent node
                if (parentNode.Right == currentNode)
                {
                    // try left side of parent node if it can have better answer
                    if (parentNode.Left != null && end <= MaxEndValue(parentNode.Left))
                    {
                        // right side tree doesn't have any answer or if the right side has
                        // an answer but left side can have better answer then try left side
                        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(result, default) ||
                            Introspector.GetStart(parentNode.Value) == Introspector.GetStart(currentNode.Value))
                        {
                            // put left as new root, and break out inner loop
                            spineNodes.Push(parentNode.Left);
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    // no left side, go one more level up
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did this source come from (link?), since that may help us have better context as to what it is trying to do...

Comment: Thanks, have added the source filename and namespace within the Roslyn source where the file can found. Also forget to mention an important point, the tree is ordered by the start value of each interval stored.